# Map filenames from folder in json string using bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

How to implement all filenames which have .yaml extension to json string from folder and it's nested folders using bash shell?

Folder example:

```
 folder/
   filename-1.yaml
   readme.md
   nested-folder/
     filename-2.yaml
     filename-3.yaml
     robots.txt
```

Expected result:

`[ { name: \"filename-1\", url: \"/names/filename-1.yaml\"}, { name: \"nested-folder/filename-2\", url: \"/names/filename-2.yaml\"}, { name: \"nested-folder/filename-3\", url: \"/names/filename-3.yaml\"} ]`

Comment: get a filename with `basename`. So just output in json format `echo "{ name: \"$(basename "${arr[$i]}" .yaml)\", url: \"$(something here too)\"}`.

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you, it works! And how to put result in one variable as json string?

Comment: @dima_bur, for any answer, `var=$(...the code...)`, as we have other Q&A entries describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far safer is to let a JSON-aware tool like `jq` figure out how to escape your names; this works even for names with quotes, tabs, literal newlines, literal backslashes, and other unusual-but-perfectly-legal characters.

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -name '*.yaml' -printf '%P\0' |
  jq -Rs '[ split("\u0000") | .[] |
            { "name": capture("^(?<name>.*)[.]yaml$").name,
              "url": "/names/\(.)" } ]'
```

Comment: @dima_bur, ...btw, I've edited this to cover the filtering-for-.yaml part of the question I missed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
DIR=/path/to/folder;

echo [ 
let I=0
find "$DIR" -name '*.yaml' | while read F; do
    let I++;
    N="$(basename "$F")";
    N="${N/%.yaml/}";
    [ $I != 1 ] && echo ,
    echo -n '  { "name": "'"$N"'", "url":"'"${F/#$DIR/}"'" }'
done
[ $I == 0 ] || echo;
echo ]
```

Comment: This fails if a file name contains a `"`.

Comment: it's also generally pretty odd code -- using the non-POSIX syntax `let`, which bash supports [only for backwards-compatibility](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) with pre-1992 non-POSIX Bourne; using `==`, which isn't compatible with any baseline POSIX shell at all, using `echo -n`, which is generally unreliable (see APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of  [the `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and the bash `xpg_echo` flag's interaction with `set -o posix`), etc.

Comment: (btw, [POSIX also specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) that only all-caps variable names can modify shell and utility behavior, leaving names with at least one lower-case character as reserved for applications to use without any chance of unintentionally modifying shell behavior).

Comment: (Also, `N="${N/%.yaml/}"` is a bashism, whereas the equivalent `N=${N%.yaml}` is both shorter and compatible with all POSIX-family shells; I would similarly consider `N=${F##*/}` as a more efficient alternative to invoking an external `basename` command -- `dirname` has some special-case logic that makes it more correct than the similar PE, but the same isn't true for `basename`).